# May 2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion

This community last had moderators appointed 6 years ago, so it's been a while... In addition to that, you may have noticed that one of the current mods — StrongBad — has stepped down from their moderator position recently, and both my and Mark's activity on the site is reduced in the recent months.

In some other SE sites a new experiment was started where beta sites also have pro-tem moderators elected. As such, to find a replacement for StrongBad, we're looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere in May 2020. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in May '20.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination. Here is the actual election announcement.

Comment: Wish I'd seen this sooner. The real question is: Do we have the user base (including the *kind of user base*) to support an election? We get lots of through traffic. But I'm not sure how many people really partake in the moderation activities of the site. The fact that this has only gotten 43 views doesn't say lot about our mod culture. I'd be interested in the job, and a few others might be as well. But it would be odd to 'win' by getting something like 4 votes in total.

Comment: @ouflak you can still answer, it'll be up to the community mods to decide if they want to have an election or not. Me personally would support you.

Comment: @ouflak https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/2020-moderator-election-announcement