# 2020 Moderator Election - Announcement

Tags: discussion, election

Expatriates will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **July 6th** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on July 6th, users can [nominate themselves](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On July 13th, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year)).
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on July 21st.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Would you please link the [questionnaire](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/2020-community-moderator-election-questionnaire?cb=1) on the [main election page](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1)? There have been some vote-swaying answers there and I think any voters should have the opportunity to see that.

Comment: @ouflak it is linked as a hyperlink for "The Candidates answer your questions", which is by default how we usually do it.

Comment: Yes! @Catija linked it for us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are moderators required to sign up to agreements that muffle their voice about criticism of StackExchange corporate policies? I'm notoriously politically incorrect. And I've [openly spoken out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story/314009#314009) [against certain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction/398490#398490) [corporate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390301/would-a-note-about-preferred-pronouns-qualify-the-same-way-as-a-thank-you/390305#390305) [objectives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer/310082#310082). It's not hard for me to imagine getting run off the site for expressing opinions that, as a normal user, perhaps wouldn't cause quite the same reaction from the company. I've demonstrated a [willingness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396479/how-can-we-stop-failing-the-users-who-we-actually-want-to-join-and-remain-as-m/398082#398082) and [eagerness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255270/are-we-losing-the-battle-against-the-close-vote-queue/255368#255368) to take on extra roles for moderating and maintaining the site, and I'm quite happy to keep that up or take on those extra responsibilities should they become available to me.

I know for myself that I would be just fine handling the extra duties and dedicating some of the already significant the time I spend on here to those tasks. But some of the company structure has clearly changed recently, and there have been certain pronouncements and actions by the company which I consider wildly off-topic, borderline offensively inappropriate, and perhaps even dangerously counterproductive. I've been active on StackExchange across a variety of sites for almost a decade and not once has my my race/ethnicity, gender/orientation, religion or immigration status (even here on Expats) played a role in my moderation efforts. As a moderator, I'd fully expect that to continue to be the case. If I'm not allowed to express those kind of opinions on here, I just question if I'm a good fit for the role of a moderator as seen from the company perspective.

Comment: You might want to read the current https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement although it's true that the part about "other moderator policies made available to me" is not too well defined at the moment. This would be a good question over the main meta though

Comment: @SztupY, I actually [asked a question about this a few days ago on the StackOverflow Meta election announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398884/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/398972#398972). There [were one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398884/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/398921#398921) or two other [similar questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398884/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/399045#399045) asked as well.